# GeoServer Imagemosaic WMS not showing

Tags: geoserver, wms, image-mosaic

I have configured a WMS service through the GeoServer web UI using a ImageMosaic store. The store points to a directory inside the data directory that contains a bunch of GeoTIFFs. When I point QGIS to the WMS service, the rasters are not displayed. Looking through the logs (currently set to verbose) I see the following message:

```
WARN [shapefile.shp] - Could not open the .shx file, continuing assuming the .shp file is not sparse
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/local/geoserver/myimagery/mymosaic.shx (No such file or directory)
```

I can confirm that the service is responding by hitting it with Postman, but it is just responding with an empty image. I can see the getMap request in the logs, but the response is not correct based on the input GeoTIFFs

Answer (score 1):

This sort of problem is usually caused by the user running GeoServer (`tomcat`?) not having write permissions to the data directory so that it can make the shapefile. Though in your case it seems to have made part of the files (`.shp`) but not the `.shx` file which might mean it is a problem with disk capacity.

In general it is bad practice to store data inside the "data" directory (which should really be known as the "config" directory.

Comment: Thanks Ian! The "data" directory is a mounted Azure disk share and should have unlimited storage capacity. The disk is mounted on the pod with read-write access, so I'm certain that the process can write whatever it wants.

I had originally mounted the imagery disk to /imagery, but when creating a imagemosaic, there were more errors. Instead, the directory is mounted to /var/local/geoserver as per the oscarfonts/geoserver default data dir.

Comment: so, does `/var/local/geoserver/myimagery/mymosaic.shx` exist or not?